# LIMIT clause is not enforced in UPDATE subquery

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I'm seeing a strange issue since upgrading to postgres 10 from 9.4. This parameterised update query used to work reliably, but now it regularly (but not always) fails to enforce the `LIMIT` clause

```
UPDATE tablename SET someValue = ? WHERE myKey IN (
  SELECT myKey 
  FROM tablename 
  WHERE status = 'good' 
  ORDER BY timestamp 
  ASC LIMIT ? FOR UPDATE
)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

SELECT ... FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED

limit ? for update skip locked is a feature added from 9.5.
with this concept, every thread just sees the records that are not locked for update by other threads and so no race occurs.